# Facebook Realtime Update: Admins of a page changes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

do you know if it is possible to get notified if a user is loosing or getting rights for a facebook-page?

I found the "admins" field for pages but it's not subscribable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not there in the subscription page, then you cannot subscribe to it. You will have to poll normally without realtime updates.